# Angular 2 Focus Directive Issues

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to create an update type function, where I select an edit button and it focuses on the description of a comment to edit. However I do not understand how to grab just the specific description of the specific post that I want to edit. Here is some of the html and the concept of what I am trying to achieve...

```
    <div>
      <p [contentEditable]="isEditable" [focus]="inputFocused">Test 1</p>
       <button (click)="Edit()">edit 1</button>
    </div>
     <div>
      <p [contentEditable]="isEditable" [focus]="inputFocused">Test 2</p>
       <button (click)="Edit()">edit 2</button>
    </div>
```

and here is a plunker with all the code directive and all https://plnkr.co/edit/HSuLScvffC0G5sfMHjJ5?p=preview

I am open to accepting that I may be approaching this the wrong way. any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that your `isEditable` and `inputFocused` variables are non-discriminatory.

Comment: Yes, but say there are 100 comments, I dont want to have to create 100 booleans to distinguish which comment I want to edit. Is there like a `this.comment.focus` type of set up I can do?

Comment: Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/yrDLST1teuJCopnPafZR?p=preview

Comment: Don't manually create, them, then: https://plnkr.co/edit/YfIE66eO7W9lMabA52Ac?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Thats perfect! thank you. could you please post an answer explaining how this works I would like to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the power of web components can come to the rescue. Create a comment component instead and encapsulate the edit logic there:

**app.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {MyComment} from './comment.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul *ngFor="let comment of comments">
        <li>
          <my-comment [comment]="comment"></my-comment>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
 private comments = ['Comment 1', 'Comment 2'];
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [App, MyComment],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**comment.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild, OnInit} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comment',
  template: `
    <div>
      <p #text>{{comment}}</p>
      <button (click)="Edit()">Edit</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class MyComment {
  @Input() comment: string;
  @ViewChild('text') paragraph: HtmlElement;

  Edit() {
    let element = this.paragraph.nativeElement;
    element.contentEditable = true;
    element.focus();
  }
}
```

A working plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/G8s8tw2R2zyrJaD1NGW0?p=preview